# mySql error 1064 for stored procedure 3

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

Help!!.... what's wrong with the below?? I am getting a SQL syntax error number 1064 for line indicated by arrow.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_IsProductInBasket (
  IN customerId INT(11),
  IN productId TINYTEXT
)
BEGIN
  SELECT
    products_id
  FROM customers_basket
  WHERE customers_id = customerId
    AND products_id = productId;    <------ error here????!!!
END
```

I've verified the select works fine as a stand alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the delimiter,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_IsProductInBasket 
(
  IN customerId INT(11),
  IN productId TINYTEXT
)
BEGIN
  SELECT   products_id
  FROM     customers_basket
  WHERE    customers_id = customerId AND 
           products_id = productId;   
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```